# Метки с «тег/тэг» в описании

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, термины

К вопросу об утверждённых переводах английских терминов.

[Метки с «тег/тэг» в кратком описании](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/355163/458540/ru-so-tags-with--in-excerpts)
[Метки с «тег/тэг» в полном описании](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/355163/458548/ru-so-tags-with--in-wiki)