# Надо ли переводить кальки с английского в описаниях меток?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, метки, правки, описание-метки

Для примера возьмём метку [python-3.6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.6). У неё такое описание:

> Версия языка программирования Python выпущена в декабре 2016 года. Для вопросов, относящихся к Python 3.6. По возможности используйте более общие **теги** [python] и [python-3.x].

Вроде бы на сайте принято название "метка", а не "тег". Но когда я предложил правку с заменой "теги" на "метки", её отклонили:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустимы ли такие правки, или они "не улучшают качество сообщения"?

Такая проблема есть как минимум на метках по Python 3.5-3.10.

Comment: Тоже самое в .NET: .NET 5 это следующая версия .NET Core ... Используйте этот **тег** для вопросов про .NET 5.

Comment: Как создатель метки .net-5, поправил её описание, спасибо.

Comment: Слово "тег" мне кажется более понятным, чем "метка".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat здесь так не принято (ц)

Comment: Зачем вообще плодить метки с каждой версией ЯП? Для чего этот зоопарк? Пусть авторы указывают версию в вопросе...

Comment: Кстати, интересный вопрос с поисковыми запросами по словам "тэг" и "тег" в кратких и полных описаниях меток: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1151/507426

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В данном случае лучше использовать тот термин, который принят на сайте для элементов его интерфейса.

Могу предложить, что правка была отклонена как "несущественная". Ведь на вопросах/ответах любые правки приводят к поднятию вопросов, и это не всегда желательно при несущественных изменениях. Также подобные отклонения правок могут стимулировать участника вносить более существенный вклад в описание метки, пока репутация ещё недостаточна для единоличной правки.

В данном случае я предлагаю подобные правки описания меток утверждать даже при таких крохотных изменениях.

Comment: Поправишь "теги" на "метки" в питонах? :)

Comment: @aepot я пока на мобильнике. Не удобно

Comment: По предлагал правок для python 3.5-3.9. На python3.10 уже не хватило (

Comment: @aepot вроде сейчас всё в "метках" уже должно быть.